# Como cerrar el proceso o la conexion con sqlite en Electron JS?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, sqlite, sqlite3, electron

Estoy desarrollando una app sencilla en Electron js y usando
electron-sqlite como db... estoy teniendo un problema y es que cuando
cierro la aplicacion queda un proceso abierto de sqlite.
tambien me di cuenta que cada que ejecuto la accion de refrescar la
aplicacion me da
una alerta en consola de memory leak:

```
 (node:17124) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory
 leak detected.
```

estoy usando el siguiente codigo para ejecutar las consultas:

```
ipcMain.handle("set-path-db", async (event, dbPath) => {
    const res = await sqlite.setdbPath(dbPath);
    return res;
});

ipcMain.handle("executeQuery", async (event, query, fetch, values) => {
    try {
        return await sqlite.executeQuery(query, fetch, values);
    } catch (error) {
        return error;
    };
});
```

Tengo sospechas deque ocurre debido a que no estoy usando ningun
codigo de sqlite.close() o algo similar pero la documentacion, no
indica que que exista esa funcion en electron-sqlite, tampoco hay
sqlite.commit() sino que al enviar la query se comitea solo...

alguien con mas experiencia que sepa a que se debe esto?

principalmente lo de que quede un proceso sqlite abierto luego de
cerrar la app. eso me preocupa ya que consume mucha memoria en segundo
plano.